# How to modify a $H^1$ weak convergence sequence so that I have the $L^2$ equi-integrability of gradient?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, sobolev-spaces, elliptic-pde, calculus-of-variations

Assume $u_n\to u$ weakly in $H^1(\Omega)$ where $\Omega\subset \mathbb R^N$ is open bounded Lipschitz boundary.

My goal is to find a new sequence $\bar u_n$ and a new function $\bar u$ such that

1. $\int_\Omega|\nabla \bar u_n|^2dx\leq \int_\Omega|\nabla u_n|^2dx$ and $\int_\Omega|\nabla \bar u|^2dx\leq \int_\Omega|\nabla u|^2dx$
2. $\bar{u}_n\to \bar{u}$ weakly in $H^1$.
3. $\nabla \bar u_n$ is $L^2$-equi-integrable, i.e., for any $\epsilon>0$ we have there exists $\delta>0$ such that for all set $T\subset \Omega$ with $\mathcal L^N(T)<\delta$ we have
   $$
   \sup_{n\in\mathbb N}\int_{T} |\nabla \bar u_n|^2dx<\epsilon. \tag 1
   $$

My idea is to define
$$
\bar u_n:=\min_{v\in\mathcal A(u_n)}\left\{\int_\Omega|\nabla v^2|\,dx\right\},\text{ and }\bar u:=\min_{v\in\mathcal A(u)}\left\{\int_\Omega|\nabla v^2|\,dx\right\},
$$
where 
$$  
\mathcal A(u_n):=\left\{v\in H^1(\Omega), T[v]=T[u_n]\right\},
$$
and $T[\cdot]$ denotes the usual trace operator.

The property $1$ is obviously true. The prove of property $2$ I put it at the end of this post. Please help me to check whether it is correct.

However, I can not prove property $3$. The best I can do is assuming $(1)$ does not hold, i.e., there exists a sequence of set $T_n\subset \Omega$ such that $\lim_{n\to 0}\mathcal L^N(T_n)=0$ and 
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty} \int_{T_n}|\nabla \bar u_n|^2dx\geq \epsilon>0
$$
and hope to have a contradiction.

We can compute
$$
\liminf_{n\to\infty}\int_\Omega|\nabla \bar u_n|^2dx\geq \liminf_{n\to\infty}\int_{\Omega\setminus T_n}|\nabla \bar u_n|^2dx+\liminf_{n\to\infty}\int_{T_n}|\nabla \bar u_n|^2dx\geq \int_\Omega|\nabla \bar u\,|^2dx+\epsilon 
$$
but I can not get any contradiction from here. I feel I need to use the minimality of $\nabla\bar u_n$ but I don't see how...

Any help of new idea of how to construct $\bar u_n$ is really welcome!

---

Below is how to proof property $2$.

Now let me prove property $2$. Clearly $\bar u_n$ is bounded in $H^1$ and hence, up to a subsequence, $\bar u_n\to u_0$ weakly in $H^1$. I only need to prove that $u_0=\bar u$. To do so, I only need to prove that $u_0$ is the weak solution of PDE
$$
\begin{cases}
-\Delta v=0, & x\in\Omega\\
v=u, & x\in\partial\Omega
\end{cases}
$$
By weak convergence in $H^1$, we have 
$$
\int_\Omega \nabla u_0\nabla \phi=0
$$
for all $\phi\in H_0^1(\Omega)$. I only need to prove that $u_0\in \mathcal A(u)$ then I would be done. To do so, I need to prove $u_0-u\in H_0^1(\Omega)$. I will claim
$$
\left|\int_\Omega (u_0-u)(x) \partial_i\varphi(x)dx\right|\leq C\|\varphi\|_{L^2(\Omega)}
$$
for all $\phi\in C_c^\infty(\mathbb R^N)$.

We observe that 
\begin{multline}
\left|\int_\Omega (u_0-u)(x) \partial_i\varphi(x)dx\right|=\\
\lim_{n\to\infty}\left|\int_\Omega (\bar u_n-u_n)(x) \partial_i\varphi(x)dx\right|=\lim_{n\to\infty}\left|\int_\Omega \partial x_i(\bar u_n-u_n)(x) \varphi(x)dx\right|\\
\leq \lim_{n\to\infty}\|\nabla (\bar u_n-u_n)\|_{L^2}\|v\|_{L^2}\leq C\|v\|_{L^2}
\end{multline}
as desired, where the 3rd inequality used the fact that $T[\bar u_n-u_n]\equiv 0$.

Hence, by the uniqueness of solution, we have $u_0=\bar u$, and hence property $2$ is true.

---

PS: I also post this problem in Math Stack Exchange [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1336295/how-to-modify-a-h1-weak-convergence-sequence-so-that-i-have-the-l2-equi-in) because this post is just an update of my yesterday's post which exist both on math Stack Exchange as well...I will avoid this problem next time. Sorry!

Comment: Since $u_n\to u$ in $H^1$, you have $\int|\nabla u_n|^2\leq1+\int|\nabla u|^2$ for $n$ large enough. Then by the energy minimizing property $\int|\nabla\bar u|^2$ is bounded uniformly in $n$. Is this what you want or did I miss something?

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta ah not really. Please see equation $(1)$ for details explanation.

Comment: @Denoising: How about $\bar u = \bar u_n \equiv 0$? This satisfies 1-3.

Comment: @gerw of course you are right. but I wish to preserve the boundary condition as well. Actually I will close this problem since I need to add/cancel some assumptions. Thank you anyway!

Comment: If you like the answer you should upvote it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the construction that you are proposing by harmonic extension does not work. Indeed consider on the unit disk $\mathbb{B}^2 \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ the function $u_n : \mathbb{B}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ defined for $x = (x_1, x_2) \in \mathbb{B}^2$
$$
  u_n (x_1, x_2) = \frac{\operatorname{Re} \bigl((x_1 + i x_2)^n\bigr)}{\sqrt{n}}.
$$

It can be checked that the function $u_n$ is harmonic on the disk $\mathbb{B}^2$, therefore $\bar{u}_n = u_n$.

Moreover, $u_n \to 0$ almost everywhere on $\mathbb{B}^2$ as $n \to \infty$,
$$
  \int_{\mathbb{B}^2} \vert \nabla u_n \vert^2 = C,
$$
where $C > 0$ does not depend on $n$, and for every compact set $K \subset \mathbb{B}^2$,
$$
  \lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{K} \vert \nabla u_n \vert^2 = 0.
$$
It follows from these facts that $u_n \rightharpoonup \bar{0} = 0$ in $H^1 (\mathbb{B}^2)$ and that the sequence $(\nabla u_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is not equiintegrable.

Comment: I see. Yea your example works... by any chance, do you know some known ways to turn/truncate a sequence to a qui-integrable sequence and somehow has the properties that I wish to have? Thank you!